# Criterion to determine the number of kernels in Expectation-Maximization algorithm

Tags: kernel-smoothing, expectation-maximization, gaussian-mixture-distribution

Suppose we have a random variable $X$, whose distribution is a Gaussian mixture $$f_K =\sum_{i = 1}^K \alpha_i N(\mu_i, \sigma^2_i)$$
where $\alpha_i> 0$, $\sum_i \alpha_i = 1$ and $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ denotes the density of normal distribution. The number of kernels $K$ as well as the other parameters of distribution is unknown.

We obtain a vector ${\bf x}$ of $n$ (i.i.d) outcomes $(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n)$. If we choose a particular $K$, then we can use EM-algorithm to estimate the other parameters.

> How to choose an appropriate $K$?

I have generated some vectors ${\bf x}$ (length of ${\bf x}$'s is $n =
2000$) with known parameters of distribution where the number of kernels was between $1$ and $6$. Then I run EM-algorithm for $K = 1, 2, \dots, 10$.

Since the only reason why I need the density $f_K$ is to (numerically) calculate probabilites $$P(a <X<b) = \int_a^b f_K(t)dt\text{,}$$
I got the idea that the good choice of $K$ would be such that $$I_K = \int_\mathbb{R}\mid f_{K}(t) - f_{K-1}(t)\mid dt <\varepsilon$$
for some $\varepsilon$. The problem is that, mostly, $I_K$'s form a decreasing sequence and it seems that the bigger the $\sigma_i$'s, the bigger the $I_K$'s, so I don't have a clue, which $\varepsilon$ would be good in general or how to somehow normalise it.

> Are there any other (common) methods of determing $K$, which would do for my purpose (computing $P(a<X<b)$)?

**EDIT:** My idea, comparing $I_K = ||f_K-f_{K-1}||_1$, was bad/not useful, since $I_K$'s vary too much. I partially solved the problem with evaluation of log-likelihood function $L(x\mid \theta_K)$, where $\theta_K$ is the vector of all unknown parameters.